# Extract elements from a vector using a sparse matrix in R without converting to dense matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I would like to extract all the elements from vector `x1` where the ith column exists in a sparse matrix. I need all of the sparse elements removed, but the results should live line-by-line in their own object/list/matrix.

**Given:**

```
> x1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> sparse_mat
8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

[1,] | | | . . . . . . .
[2,] . | | | . . . . . .
[3,] . . | | | . . . . .
[4,] . . . | | | . . . .
[5,] . . . . | | | . . .
[6,] . . . . . | | | . .
[7,] . . . . . . | | | .
[8,] . . . . . . . | | |
```

**Desired Results:**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    4
[3,]    3    4    5
[4,]    4    5    6
[5,]    5    6    7
[6,]    6    7    8
[7,]    7    8    9
[8,]    8    9   10
```

---

### More complete example with commentary

```
library(Matrix)
library(purrr)

x1 <- 1:10

create_seq_sparse <- function(n, len) {
  bandSparse(m = n, n = n - len + 1L, k = seq_len(len) - 1L)
}

sparse_mat <- create_seq_sparse(10, 3)
sparse_mat
#> 8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
#>                         
#> [1,] | | | . . . . . . .
#> [2,] . | | | . . . . . .
#> [3,] . . | | | . . . . .
#> [4,] . . . | | | . . . .
#> [5,] . . . . | | | . . .
#> [6,] . . . . . | | | . .
#> [7,] . . . . . . | | | .
#> [8,] . . . . . . . | | |

# If there's a better way to do this, please advise?
mat_x1_mult_sparse <- t(t(sparse_mat) * x1) 
mat_x1_mult_sparse
#> 8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                          
#> [1,] 1 2 3 . . . . . .  .
#> [2,] . 2 3 4 . . . . .  .
#> [3,] . . 3 4 5 . . . .  .
#> [4,] . . . 4 5 6 . . .  .
#> [5,] . . . . 5 6 7 . .  .
#> [6,] . . . . . 6 7 8 .  .
#> [7,] . . . . . . 7 8 9  .
#> [8,] . . . . . . . 8 9 10

# This is nice, but can't use in conjunction with keep?
# mat_x1_mult_sparse[1, , drop = FALSE] 

# Desired results, but this approach I think I lose the advantages of the sparse matrix?
mat_x1_mult_sparse[1, ] %>% keep(~ .x != 0)
#> [1] 1 2 3
mat_x1_mult_sparse[2, ] %>% keep(~ .x != 0)
#> [1] 2 3 4
# etc...
mat_x1_mult_sparse[8, ] %>% keep(~ .x != 0)
#> [1]  8  9 10
```

Comment: Would `matrix(na.omit(c(t(replace(col(sparse_mat), which(!sparse_mat), NA)))), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)` this help?

Comment: @akrun, interesting, and it might, but I should have been more clear or provided a better example. This doesn't help in the case that `x1 <- 11:20` in which case the results would be `11 12 13 | 12 13 14 | ...etc...`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were working with the column index.  In that case, get the index with `summary` i.e. `i1 <- summary(sparse_mat);
 i2 <- as.matrix(i1[order(i1[,1]),]);
 matrix(mat_x1_mult_sparse[i2], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun I believe that will do the trick. Feel free to post as an answer. Is there a better way to create `mat_x1_mult_sparse` than with `mat_x1_mult_sparse <- t(t(sparse_mat) * x1) `?

Comment: Instead of doing double transpose, may be replicate the 'x1' and multiply i.e. `sparse_mat * x1[col(sparse_mat)]`

Answer (score 4):

One option is to make use of the `summary` method to get the index of the elements that are not sparse

```
library(Matrix)
i1 <- summary(sparse_mat)
i2 <- as.matrix(i1[order(i1[,1]),]) # order by the row index
# multiply the sparse matrix by the replicated 'x1', extract elements
# with i2 index and convert it to n column matrix
matrix((sparse_mat * x1[col(sparse_mat)])[i2], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
#.     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    2    3    4
#[3,]    3    4    5
#[4,]    4    5    6
#[5,]    5    6    7
#[6,]    6    7    8
#[7,]    7    8    9
#[8,]    8    9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

Erased earlier answer once I noticed you don't want to leave your matrix being sparse; still, the idea is to leverage the `i` slot of your matrix:

```
# convert to dgCMatrix since ngCMatrix can only be on/off
out = as(sparse_mat, 'dgCMatrix')

# subset to the "on" elements of sparse_mat, 
#   and replace with the column number. The column number is
#   not stored directly so we have to make it ourselves, basically
#   by looking for when the value in @i stays the same or goes down
out[sparse_mat] = c(1L, cumsum(diff(sparse_mat@i) <= 0) + 1L)
out
# 8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#                          
# [1,] 1 2 3 . . . . . .  .
# [2,] . 2 3 4 . . . . .  .
# [3,] . . 3 4 5 . . . .  .
# [4,] . . . 4 5 6 . . .  .
# [5,] . . . . 5 6 7 . .  .
# [6,] . . . . . 6 7 8 .  .
# [7,] . . . . . . 7 8 9  .
# [8,] . . . . . . . 8 9 10
```

This should be extremely efficient since the `[` method for `dgCMatrix` should be smart and your replacement is *exactly* the length desired (no wasted elements).